# Testing ActiveMerchant with cucumber/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, activemerchant

How do I test Paypal Express Gateway with cucumber(with capybara) and activemerchant.  I have ActiveMerchant in test mode, and I'm wanting to test the process of testing out my shopping cart.  Eventually want to use VCR as well.

Any tips or pointers as googling has not turned up any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the app online to heroku (create staging environment if you like) and then test with saucelabs.com and sauce_ruby [link](https://github.com/sauce-labs/sauce_ruby). This gives you a selenium connector that you can use with your rspec/cucumber(also capybara) tests and it can record the video output of the test to the website while the test result shows in your console.